# list to dictionary comprehensions

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I'm practicing some python syntax exercises and I decided to write a dictionary comprehension based on a similarly designed list comprehension. But while the later is OK, the former results in a syntax error.

This is my list comprehension..

```
>>> l = [z**z if z%2 else z for z in range(5)]
[0, 1, 2, 27, 4]
```

and this is my dictionary comprehension..

```
>>> d = {z:z**z if z%2 else z:z for z in range(5)}
                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

is there a way to write a dictionary comprehension that is similar in design to my list comprehension?

Comment: Yes, just like in the list comp you write `else z`. Read it as `z:(z**z if z%2 else z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write

```
In [16]: d = {z:z**z if z%2 else z for z in range(5)}
In [17]: d
Out[17]: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 27, 4: 4}
```

which is easier to read if you supply parentheses:

```
In [18]: d = {z:(z**z if z%2 else z) for z in range(5)}
In [19]: d
Out[19]: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 27, 4: 4}
```

The enclosed part is a [Python ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) for the value, *not* for the (key, value) pair.

> @timgeb but what if he also wants to change the key too in the else?

(Let's assume we want `z*10`.) In cases like this, you could write something like

```
In [24]: d = {(z*10 if z%2 else z):(z**z if z%2 else z) for z in range(5)}
In [25]: d
Out[25]: {0: 0, 10: 1, 4: 4, 2: 2, 30: 27}
```

but this is inefficient because `z%2` is computed twice.

It is better to make use of the fact that the `dict` constructor takes an iterable of two-element iterables:

```
In [26]: dict((z*10, z**z) if z%2 else (z, z) for z in range(5))
Out[26]: {0: 0, 10: 1, 4: 4, 2: 2, 30: 27}
```

Comment: If the computed condition is expensive, a slightly more efficient way to avoid repeating it is like this: `{(z*10 if k else z):(z**z if k else z) for z in range(5) for k in [z%2]}`.

Comment: @ekhumoro that's pretty clever, but in the end using the `dict` constructor with tuples still wins :)

Comment: For me, `dict()` is about 20% slower than the comprehensions. (Tested using `timeit`, with 100k iterations).

Comment: @ekhumoro Interesting! Then only readability and `k` with complex `__bool__` implementations remain to be discussed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{z:z**z if z%2 else z for z in range(5)}
```

Output:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 27, 4: 4}
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {z:z**z if z%2 else z for z in range(5)}
print(d)
```

Gives output:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 27, 4: 4}
```